# How to fast estimate the projected area of cube in perspective view?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, math, graphics, 3d

I can calculate the accurate area by project those triangles face to the camera. But it is slow. So is there any algorithm to estimate the area in a faster way with a given error bound?

Comment: Slow ? How can that be slow ? There are only three visible faces, at most 6 triangles ! How do you perform that ?

Comment: 1. find the triangles by the angle of view direction and normal of triangle.

Comment: 1. find the triangles by the dot-product(>0) of view direction and normal of triangle.

2. calculate the vertex projected coordinates.

3. calculate the area for each triangle.

Besides, I'd like to use this algorithm in a javascript environment.

Comment: But why do you say that this is slow ??? The running time is barely measurable.

Comment: 1. for dot product, 3 * 3 multiplications.   
dot(v1,v2) = v1x*v2x + v1y*v2y + v1z*v2z.   
2. for projection vertex, 8 * 7 multiplications.   
(px,py) = (x,y,z,1) * viewmatrix   
at most 7 vertex.    
3. for area, 2 * 6 multiplications.   
   S = (x1-x0)*(y2-y1)+(x2-x0)*(y0-y1)

Comment: if using bounding sphere to estimate.  
1. project center to depth, 3 multiplications   
float w = x * matrix.r0.w + y * matrix.r1.w + z * matrix.r2.w + matrix.r3.w   
2. estimate the area, 1 multiplications.   

It's fast, but rough espcially for big different dimentions.

Comment: This is probably below a microsecond, so why do you care ? Slow compared to what ? A reasonable approximation will probably cost the half or the third, so what's the benefit ?

Answer (score 3):

Approximate the cube with a sphere, project the sphere and find out the area (the projections is an ellipse scaled down by a factor of the distance).

It's a bit rough but will work well in many cases.

Comment: Thanks, it works well when the three dimensions are about the same. I'd like to fix those boxes with big different dimensions.

Comment: How can a cube have big different dimensions ??

Comment: @Sorin: no, the projection of a sphere is an ellipse. To approximate it with a tight circle, one needs to estimate the center and axis, which is pretty uneasy. Even for a loose circle, the scale factor isn't so straightforward.

Comment: For a box with extends of x,y,z(1,2,5), I am thinking about to estimate the project area with the area of three face(2,10,5), the angle of face and scale factor.